# Response.TransmitFile vs. Direct Link

Tags: asp.net, cloud, azure-storage

I am using a Azure cloud storage solution, and as such, each file has it's own URL. I need to allow users to download files such as PDFs from our ASP .Net website. Currently, we are using Response.TransmitFile to send the file to the client's browser, but this requires that we fetch the data from the cloud storage and then send it to the client (seems like an inefficient way to do it).

I'm wondering if we could not just have a direct link to the file, and if so, how would this differ from the Response.TrnasmitFile method? That is, without the TransmitFile method, we cannot set the Content-type header, etc... How does that effect anything?

Thanks

Comment: If the file has already a URL and that URL is accessible by the client, then it's better to send the link and let the storage system handle all the gory stuff (content type, ranges, etc.) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I stay away from using Response.TransmitFile as it does require that you fetch the file and then stream it down to the client.

The only times I have used it was to protect files and only serve them to users that had permission to access them instead of just linking directly to the file.

If the files you are serving are public, then I would recommend just linking to them. If all you need is to set the Content-Type header, then simply make sure the .pdf extension is mapped to the correct MIME type (application/pdf).